# NameError is showing on rObject whereas it is already mentioned in line 3

Tags: nameerror

The code is:

```
 def get_audio(): 

        rObject= sr.Recognizer() 
        audio= '' 

 with sr.Microphone() as source: 
        print("Speak...") 


        audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 5)  
        print("Stop.") # limit 5 secs 

 try: 

        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US') 
        print("You : ", text) 
        return text 

 except: 

        assistant_speaks("Could not understand your audio, PLease try again !") 
return 0
```

`NameError` is reported on `rObject` whereas it is mentioned in line 3.

Comment: What is the exact error reported ?

Comment: audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit_ = 5)